# Generating series of map for each field of attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, atlas

Using QGIS 2.8, I have a shapefile with more than 30 columns (or fields) in the attribute table. I would like to automate the creation of one map for each of them.

I gathered that the QGIS Atlas generator can do that by "line" of the field, how to do that by column?

I found [Generate series of maps with Python script](http://www.qgis.nl/2013/08/13/python-script-to-generate-series-of-maps/?lang=en), but I am on MacOS ...

Comment: Look at this answer, it helped me a lot: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234975/automating-atlas-to-create-maps-for-all-attributes/235144#235144

Answer (score 2):

You can't do an atlas map by Column.

You could get your dataset into Excel and TRANSPOSE it, but really, you need to set up your data structure for the Atlas so that there is a single attribute that has one row for each map you want to make.

Answer (score 1):

Transpose the document as the previous post stated.  Use the auto increment tool in the Q processor toolbox to add a differing numeric value to each column attribute if any match. Explode the single polygon into multiple by the newly auto generated values centroid.