# Legend and Attribute Table change throughout map composer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer, legend, atlas

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 (Las Palmas)
For a project I have about 15 maps with the same extent, where each map displays a different attribute. I have followed [Automating Atlas to create maps for all Attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234975/automating-atlas-to-create-maps-for-all-attributes/235144#235144) and it works perfectly.

Two things are not working as they should: 
- I would like to add a legend to each map (I wouldnt mind doing so manually), but every time I go back and forth though the maps, the last legend created is set for all the maps. Since all maps display something different, I really need to make sure that each map has its own legend.

I'm adding the attribute table with the relevant parameters I want to show, but - as with the Legend - all 15 maps show the same attribute Table.

Do you have any suggestions how I can make sure that each map in the Atlas have its own Legend and Attribute Table?

Answer (score 0):

Attribute table shows features controlled by Atlas if relation between tables has been done.
Relations are defined in Project properties.
Then on Atlas must select 'Relation children'.